# Uncaught (in promise) Error while opening and doing transaction on private ethereum blockchain using web3 and go-ethereum

Tags: reactjs, web3js, geth

I am trying to integrate a react app with go-ethereum using web3js.

an event Onsubmit will do the following:
1. Create an account.
2. Open the account.
3. Approve a smart contract with the created account.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';
```

....

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {requester : '', receiver:'', balance: '', message:''};
  }

 async  componentDidMount(){
    const requester = await auth.methods.requester().call();
    const receiver = await auth.methods.receiver().call();
    const approvers = await auth.methods.approvers(0).call();
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(auth.options.address);

    this.setState({requester,receiver,balance});

  }

  onSubmit = async (event)=>{
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('Approving the smart contract ..... Mining in process ! ');

      var pass = "xxxxxxx"

      var newaccount = web3.eth.personal.newAccount(pass);

      var promise1 = Promise.resolve(newaccount);


      promise1.then(function(value) {
        var accountnumber = value;
        console.log(accountnumber);
        web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(accountnumber,pass, 1500);    
        auth.methods.approve().send({gas: '1000000',from: accountnumber});

        console.log('Smart Contract approved ! ');


            });
  };
```

The account is getting created but while doing the transaction I am receiving the following error.

> Approving the smart contract ..... Mining in process !  App.js:57
>
> 0x98f76b2673d545F55c0ff1e961f15EF0a7DfBaD3

App.js:71 Smart Contract

> approved !  errors.js:29 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error:
>   authentication needed: password or unlock
>       at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:29)
>       at index.js:125
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (index.js:103)
>       at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (xml-http-request-event-target.js:50)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (xml-http-request.js:288)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (xml-http-request.js:459)
>       at push../node_modules/stream-http/lib/response.js.exports.IncomingMessage.
>   (xml-http-request.js:413)
>       at push../node_modules/stream-http/lib/response.js.exports.IncomingMessage.emit
>   (events.js:139)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1030)
>       at afterTickTwo (index.js:31)
>       at Item.push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:167)
>       at drainQueue (browser.js:131) ErrorResponse @ errors.js:29 (anonymous) @ index.js:125 request.onreadystatechange @ index.js:103
>   XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent @
>   xml-http-request-event-target.js:50 XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState @
>   xml-http-request.js:288 XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd @
>   xml-http-request.js:459 (anonymous) @ xml-http-request.js:413 emit @
>   events.js:139 endReadableNT @ _stream_readable.js:1030 afterTickTwo @
>   index.js:31 push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run @
>   browser.js:167 drainQueue @ browser.js:131 setTimeout (async)
>   _fireError @ index.js:72 sendTxCallback @ index.js:465 (anonymous) @ index.js:125 request.onreadystatechange @ index.js:103
>   XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent @
>   xml-http-request-event-target.js:50 XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState @
>   xml-http-request.js:288 XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd @
>   xml-http-request.js:459 (anonymous) @ xml-http-request.js:413 emit @
>   events.js:139 endReadableNT @ _stream_readable.js:1030 afterTickTwo @
>   index.js:31 push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run @
>   browser.js:167 drainQueue @ browser.js:131 setTimeout (async)
>   runTimeout @ browser.js:43
>   push../node_modules/process/browser.js.process.nextTick @
>   browser.js:156 nextTick @ index.js:30 maybeReadMore @
>   _stream_readable.js:521 addChunk @ _stream_readable.js:300 readableAddChunk @ _stream_readable.js:278
>   push../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js.Readable.push
>   @ _stream_readable.js:242 (anonymous) @ response.js:47 write @
>   response.js:44

Edit: Changed the code to catch the errors

```
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(accountnumber,pass, 1500, function(err, result){
          if(err){
            alert("Error"+ err);
            return;}
          alert("Account Opening: "+ result);});
```

.....

```
auth.methods.approve().send({gas: '1000000',from: accountnumber}, function(err, result){
      if(err){
        alert("Error"+ err);
        return;}
      alert("Account address: "+ result);
      console.log('Smart Contract approved ! ');});
```

The `web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount` is returning "true" but the still the `auth.methods.approve` is giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some major changes to the code, I am able to do the following from an onSubmit event on a react app.

1. Create an account.
2. Transfer some gas to it.
3. Unlock the account.
4. Sign a contract with the account.

Here is the code

```
onSubmit = async (event)=>{
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('Approving the smart contract ..... Mining in process ! ');

      var pass = "passsword1"

      var newaccount = web3.eth.personal.newAccount(pass);

      var promise1 = Promise.resolve(newaccount);


      promise1.then(function(value) {
        var accountnumber = value;
        console.log(accountnumber);
        web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('0x197022acd263e8be0f6b65b10d1e5cdbaa244c17',"*****", 1500, function(err, result){
          if(err){
            alert("Error"+ err);
            return;
          }else {
          alert("Parent Opening: "+ result);
          web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          from: "0x197022acd263e8be0f6b65b10d1e5cdbaa244c17",
          to: accountnumber, 
          value: '100000000000000000', 
          }, function(err, transactionHash) {
          if (err) { 
              console.log(err); 
          } else {
            web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(accountnumber,pass, 1500, function(err, result){
              if(err){
                alert("Error"+ err);
                return;
              }else{
                console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(accountnumber));
                alert("Child Opening: "+ result);
                auth.methods.approve().send({gas: '20000000',from: accountnumber}, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                  alert("Error"+ err);
                  return;
                }else{
                  console.log("Account address: "+ result);
                  console.log('Smart Contract approved ! ');

                }
                });
              }
            });
          }
          });
       }

      });
};
```